# Separate data frame depending on one column duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, subset

I have a large data frame with a lot of rows and columns. In one column there are characters, some of them occur only once, other multiple times. I would now like to separate the whole data frame, so that I end up with two data frames, one with all the rows that have characters that repeat themselves in this one column and another one with all the rows with the charcaters that occur only once. Like for example:

```
One = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Two = c(4,5,3,6,2,7,1,8,1,9)
Three = c("a", "b", "c", "d","d","e","f","e","g","c")
df <- data.frame(One, Two, Three)

> df
    One Two Three
1    1   4     a
2    2   5     b
3    3   3     c
4    4   6     d
5    5   2     d
6    6   7     e
7    7   1     f
8    8   8     e
9    9   1     g
10  10   9     c
```

I wish to have two data frames like

```
> dfSingle
    One Two Three
1    1   4     a
2    2   5     b
7    7   1     f
9    9   1     g

> dfMultiple
    One Two Three
3    3   3     c
4    4   6     d
5    5   2     d
6    6   7     e
8    8   8     e
10  10   9     c
```

I tried with the `duplicated()` function

```
dfSingle = subset(df, !duplicated(df$Three))
dfMultiple = subset(df, duplicated(df$Three))
```

but it does not work as the first of the "c", "d" and "e" go to the "dfSingle".
I also tried to do a for-loop

```
MulipleValues = unique(df$Three[c(which(duplicated(df$Three)))])
dfSingle = data.frame()
x = 1
dfMultiple = data.frame()
y = 1
for (i in 1:length(df$One)) {
  if(df$Three[i] %in% MulipleValues){
    dfMultiple[x,] = df[i,]
    x = x+1
    } else {
    dfSingle[y,] = df[i,]
    y = y+1
  }
}
```

It seems to do the right thing as the data frames have now the right amont of rows but they somehow have 0 columns.

```
> dfSingle
data frame with 0 columns and 4 rows
> dfMultiple
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base R, we can use `split` with `duplicated` which will return you list of two dataframes.

```
df1 <- split(df, duplicated(df$Three) | duplicated(df$Three, fromLast = TRUE))
df1

#$`FALSE`
#  One Two Three
#1   1   4     a
#2   2   5     b
#7   7   1     f
#9   9   1     g

#$`TRUE`
#   One Two Three
#3    3   3     c
#4    4   6     d
#5    5   2     d
#6    6   7     e
#8    8   8     e
#10  10   9     c
```

where `df1[[1]]` can be considered as `dfSingle` and `df1[[2]]` as `dfMultiple`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` one for fun,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(Three) %>% 
 mutate(new = n() > 1) %>% 
 split(.$new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`FALSE`
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   Three [4]
>     One   Two Three new  
>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl>
> 1     1     4 a     FALSE
> 2     2     5 b     FALSE
> 3     7     1 f     FALSE
> 4     9     1 g     FALSE
>
> $`TRUE`
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
> # Groups:   Three [3]
>     One   Two Three new  
>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl>
> 1     3     3 c     TRUE 
> 2     4     6 d     TRUE 
> 3     5     2 d     TRUE 
> 4     6     7 e     TRUE 
> 5     8     8 e     TRUE 
> 6    10     9 c     TRUE
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A way with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_split(Duplicated = (add_count(., Three) %>% pull(n)) > 1)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    One   Two Three Duplicated
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl>     
1     1     4 a     FALSE     
2     2     5 b     FALSE     
3     7     1 f     FALSE     
4     9     1 g     FALSE     

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    One   Two Three Duplicated
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl>     
1     3     3 c     TRUE      
2     4     6 d     TRUE      
3     5     2 d     TRUE      
4     6     7 e     TRUE      
5     8     8 e     TRUE      
6    10     9 c     TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using base R

```
One = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Two = c(4,5,3,6,2,7,1,8,1,9)
Three = c("a", "b", "c", "d","d","e","f","e","g","c")
df <- data.frame(One, Two, Three)

str(df)

df$Three <- as.character(df$Three)
df$count <- as.numeric(ave(df$Three,df$Three,FUN = length))

dfSingle = subset(df,df$count == 1)
dfMultiple = subset(df,df$count > 1)
```